# Как сделать так, чтобы писался username в комментариях, а не unknown author при использовании расширения Rmrevin yii2-comments?

Tags: php, yii2

Я использую [расширение](https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-comments) для yii2, чтобы добавлять комментарии.

Комментарии добавляются, однако не видно, кто добавил комментарий. Вместо username пишется "unknown author". Сделано всё исходя из приведённой выше ссылки.

В самом плагине стала искать, как достаётся имя комментатора. В vendor/rmrevin/yii2-comments/widgets/views/comment-list.php есть это:

```
<?php
$avatar = false;
$name = Yii::t('app', 'Unknown author');
$url = false;

if ($Author instanceof Comments\interfaces\CommentatorInterface) {
$avatar = $Author->getCommentatorAvatar();
$name = $Author->getCommentatorName();
$name = empty($name) ? Yii::t('app', 'Unknown author') : $name;
$url = $Author->getCommentatorUrl();
}
```

Вот здесь `$name = Yii::t('app', 'Unknown author');` можно поменять на `$name = Yii::t('app', Yii::$app->user->identity->username);`

Но тогда, конечно, будет всегда юзернейм текущего пользователя.

Comment: Yii не знаю, но очевидно что имя автора определяется в этих строках
          
          `$name = $Author->getCommentatorName();
          $name = empty($name) ? Yii::t('app', 'Unknown author') : $name;

Так что эта строка `$name = Yii::t('app', 'Unknown author');` тут непричем.
Попробуйте посмотреть код метода `getCommentatorName()` и что вообще находится в модели Author. Возможно не так настроена таблица.

Comment: @apelsinka223 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.